# Does CreateBufferedCopy leave the stream position at the end?

Tags: c#, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

In the `AfterReceiveRequest` method, if I do:

```
MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
Message requestCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();

//handle message stuff here

request = newMessage;
buffer.Close();
```

Does the above leave the position of the stream at the end? Basically what I am asking is does creating a buffered copy cause any issues when reading the request again?

This is how I arrived at this situation, In the message inspector, I originally did not create a buffered copy, but then I ran into the error message, the request has already been read after sending a request to the service and after researching online, I found out I needed to create a copy of the message and I just want to make sure this does not cause any issues with position or anything else?

I guess by creating a copy to use in the message inspector, I am not reading the message twice, the copy is read once for logging and when it is assigned to the ref param, that one is used when I make a call to the service, correct?

Comment: A network stream is not Seekable anyway. So that last part, reading the request again, is your real problem.

Comment: Maybe I am a bit misinformed, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reuse a message multiple times you have to create an in-memory copy of it. For that use the CreateBufferCopy of the message object instance. The call of this method will not alter the state of your message.

> Does the above leave the position of the stream at the end?
>   Does not apply for this type of stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have used it in my project. It shows how you make a copy of the message properly in the BeforeSendReply method. Not the method you're looking to use but the same code should apply:

```
    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var properties = reply.Properties;
        var contextKey = GetContextKey(properties);
        bool statusCodeFound = false;
        var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        if (properties.Keys.Contains("httpResponse"))
        {
            statusCode = ((System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageProperty)properties["httpResponse"]).StatusCode;
            statusCodeFound = true;
        }
        var buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

        //Must use a buffer rather than the origonal message, because the Message's body can be processed only once.
        Message msg = buffer.CreateMessage();

        //Setup StringWriter to use as input for our StreamWriter
        //This is needed in order to capture the body of the message, because the body is streamed.
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        msg.WriteMessage(xmlTextWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Flush();
        xmlTextWriter.Close();

        var returnValue = stringWriter.ToString();

        // I do my logging of the "returnValue" variable here. You can do whatever you want.

        //Return copy of origonal message with unaltered State
        reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
    }
```